# MDF Version Selection

Tags: sql-server, database, version, localdb, mdf

I'm having errors

The database 'PATHTO.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 852. This server supports version 752 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database 'PATHTO.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.

I'm creating the database on the server side with using some sql scripts. I have the ability to change database creation code so my question is that **is there a way to select mdf file version while creating the database?**

Comment: Also the interesting thing here is that I'm using below files to create the database and the mdf file, it creates version 852 instead of version 752
edit:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll

Comment: What do you mean by selecting mdf version when creating database? You create a database by using the CREATE DATABASE statement. Sounds like you are trying to attach a database that was already created. You cannot attach a database from a newer version to an older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot manipulate the value; it is internal to the file and based entirely on the database engine. If you intend to develop code, you need to be aware of which versions you need to support and make sure that any database instance you use is compatible.